# Find all combination that sum to a number

Tags: c#, .net, recursion

Given a positive integer n  find and all sets of positive integers that sum to n

```
so 4 would be 
1 1 1 1 
2 1 1
3 1
2 2
```

I think this is producing the correct numbers but I cannot figure out how to package the results.

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> BreakMeDown(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1, j = n - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
    {
        List<int> breakMeDown = new List<int>();
        breakMeDown.Add(i);
        breakMeDown.Add(j);
        yield return breakMeDown;
        //Debug.WriteLine($"{i} {j}"); 
        foreach (List<int> li in BreakMeDown(i))
            yield return li;
        foreach (List<int> li in BreakMeDown(j))
            yield return li;                               
    }
}

// test
foreach (List<int> li in BreakMeDown(7))
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", li));
```

Comment: Is the question actually, "find all **pairs** of positive integers that sum to n"? As far as I can tell, your algorithm always produces lists of length 2, but many numbers may be expressed as the sum of 3, 4, etc. addends.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin It  evaluates a pair at a time but with recursion it breaks it all the way down to produce all.  It just does not know how to package / group.  It you look at the output only a few sum to 7 but there is a sum of sum that sums to 7.   If you comment out the recursion you get the pairs.

Comment: I think maybe i concatenated with each breakdown of j, j concatenated with each breakdown of i, and cartesian product of i and j's sets of breakdowns. That should cover all cases

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Not following but if you will post an answer I will test and accept it if works.

Comment: Do you want to get `{1,1,1,3}` for 6 and etc or only want to get a pairs for 6?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Yes I want to get all including {1,1,1,3}

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var li in BreakMeDown(7))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", li));
}

public static IEnumerable<IReadOnlyCollection<int>> BreakMeDown(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1, j = n - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
    {
        foreach (var li in BreakMeDown(j).Select(bd => bd.Concat(new[] {i}).ToList()))
            yield return li;
        foreach (var li in BreakMeDown(i).Select(bd => bd.Concat(new[] {j}).ToList()))
            yield return li;
        yield return new[] {i, j};
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Okay, so based on the comments you want to deduplicate the resulting sequences. In this case, the right data structure to use is a dictionary mapping integers to number of occurrences. E.g. `{ 1: 5 }` represents a possible breakdown of 5, in which the number 1 is repeated 5 times.

Here is the code (I took a dependency on MoreLinq and Json.NET because I didn't want to implement DistinctBy and IEqualityComparer for Dictionary, but you can do these yourself if you want):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (var li in BreakMeDown(5).DistinctBy(JsonConvert.SerializeObject))
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", li));
    }

    static IImmutableDictionary<int, int> Increment(this IImmutableDictionary<int, int> dict, int i)
    {
        return dict.SetItem(i, dict.TryGetValue(i, out int iCount) ? iCount + 1 : 1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IImmutableDictionary<int, int>> BreakMeDown(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1, j = n - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
        {
            var iAndJ = ImmutableSortedDictionary.Create<int, int>().Increment(i).Increment(j);
            var bdJ = BreakMeDown(j).Select(bd => bd.Increment(i));
            var bdI = BreakMeDown(i).Select(bd => bd.Increment(j));

            var list = bdI.Concat(bdJ).Concat(new[] { iAndJ });
            foreach (var li in list)
            {
                yield return li;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could downvoter please explain what the problem is? The answer correctly computes all sequences that sum to the desired number.

Comment: This is awesome.  I up voted and it has not down votes at this time.   I don't mean to be greed but it is producing duplicates.  { 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 } = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 }  Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, the way the algorithm works the breakdown of `i` and `j` may produce duplicates. The fix is very easy, just concat the two breakdowns and map over them to produce sets instead of `IReadOnlyCollection`s, then use `Distinct`. I'll set this up and update the answer.

Comment: @Paparazzi Ok, I've updated the answer so the results don't contain duplicates.

Comment: Isn't it much simpler though? Duplicates happen when `i == j`, simply return one branch when that happens, not both. I might be wrong, can't test it right now.

Comment: @InBetween No, because duplicates can happen inside the branches for `i` and `j`. Unless you want to treat `{ 1, 2, 1 }` as being distinct from `{ 2, 1, 1 }`.

Comment: Yes, I think thats what the OP wants, order is relevant (I agree that if order is irrelevant then my proposal is wrong).

Comment: @InBetween So your answer is wrong then, because in OP's comment above they mention `{ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 } = { 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1 }` as an example of duplicates they do not want.

Comment: I am not finding IImmutableDictionary on my system.  It looks like I need to install off Nuget.   Is that correct?

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes, if you're using a .NET Core console application that'll be there by default. If you're not, you need to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this (can't test it now so I'm not 100% positive it will work as expected):

```
public static IEnumerable<List<int>> BreakMeDown(int n)
{
    for (int i = 1, j = n - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
    {
        List<int> breakMeDown = new List<int>();
        breakMeDown.Add(i);
        breakMeDown.Add(j);
        yield return breakMeDown;

        foreach (List<int> li in BreakMeDown(i))
            yield return breakMeDown.Skip(1)
                                    .Concat(li)
                                    .ToList();

        if (i != j)
        {
            foreach (List<int> li in BreakMeDown(j))
                yield return breakMeDown.Take(1)
                                        .Concat(li)
                                        .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

When you build the recursive breakdowns, you need to concatenate the result to the already built 2 factor breakdown ignoring the factor you are breaking down further.

Comment: There still some duplicates e.g.  1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1

Comment: @Paparazzi hmmm, exact duplicates should only happen when the breakdown both ways is the same, that should only happen when `i == j` (I admit I haven't thought it through completely but its sounds sound)... see edit and give it a try and lets me know if it did the trick

Comment: Still some duplicates